# How do I select from each column one specific index?

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine I have a pandas.Dataframe like:

```
x = DataFrame({ 'a': [7,6,8,0,2,5],
            'b': [3,4,5,6,7,8],
            'c': [3,8,5,6,0,1]}, index=[1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

then, I have a pandas.Series that gives me, for each key, a specific index I want to select:

```
y = Series([4,1,6], index=['a','b','c'])
```

Is there someway I could locate these indexes in the best pandas way? 
I wish to avoid looping over the pandas.Series or the pandas.Dataframe, and I prefer using commands like .loc, .query and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of `loc` and `np.diagonal` to achieve this:

```
In [26]:

np.diagonal(x.loc[y])
Out[26]:
array([0, 3, 1], dtype=int64)
```

`loc` here will perform row label lookup:

```
In [27]:

x.loc[y]
Out[27]:
   a  b  c
4  0  6  6
1  7  3  3
6  5  8  1
```

[`np.diagonal`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html) returns the values in the diagonal.

To make this robust to column order we can specifically use the values for the label lookup and the index for the columns to select:

```
In [30]:

np.diagonal(x.loc[y.values, y.index])
Out[30]:
array([0, 3, 1], dtype=int64)
```

The above will work with even if the columns in `y` are a different order than `x` column order.

Comment: I was aware of .loc behavior in this case, that's why I wanted something that could partially solve that. Indeed, numpy.diagonal is a good idea. I wish pandas had something like that implemented.

Comment: @Galdaran it looks like they did in [`0.14.0`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.14.1/generated/pandas.Index.diagonal.html) but this is no longer in the latest versions possibly due to the refactor to ndframe and ndarray rather than numpy array

Comment: However, applying numpy.diagonal does not return another pandas.Series, but an array.

Comment: @Galdaran does that matter? You can construct a Series from it if you wish

Comment: I know, but the code becomes less elegant. I'm just pointing out.